# How to add multiple but specific rows from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I'm trying to add a specific set rows that are in one data to another and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm sure there is a better way than adding one row at a time.

```
df1= pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 'John'], ['b', 2, 'Marry'], ['c', 3, 'Debbie']], columns= ['letter', 'number', 'names'])
df2= pd.DataFrame([['w', 6, 'Jim'], ['x', 33, 'Paul'], ['r', 12, 'Logan']],['m', 10, 'Olive']],['j', 88, 'Maya']], columns= ['letter', 'number', 'names'])
```

I want to be able to take the first 3 rows from df2 that contain the information for Jim, Paul, and Logan and add it to df1.

Thank you in advance for all of the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) together with [`.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) as follows:

```
df1 = df1.append(df2.iloc[:3]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
  letter  number   names
0      a       1    John
1      b       2   Marry
2      c       3  Debbie
3      w       6     Jim
4      x      33    Paul
5      r      12   Logan
```

[`.reset_index(drop=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) is used to re-serialize the index

Comment: That worked so nicely and the info on how to re-serialize the index was really helpful! Thank you so much for the help and the explanation.